# fetching data as scrolling down in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a twitter like app developed in rails 3.2.1. In my index page, I want to show the tweets posted by me and from the people whom I follow. Its working properly. Now what I need is to avoid the fetching of all the tweets. At first, I may need only the first 15 tweets then as I scrolls down, next batch of 15 or 20 tweets must append at the bottom just like what facebook and twitter does.

My index action looks like this:

```
 def index
     @tweets=Tweet.find(:all,:include =>[:user])
end
```

My view part is now fetching all the tweets and it looks like this:

```
 <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
      <% if tweet.user==current_user || current_user.following?(tweet.user) %>
         <div class="marginer">
             <%= tweet.user.user_name %> : <%= tweet.message %> 
         </div>
      <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by means of AJAX calls to your server with the user details, batch size and the start index of the batch.

Comment: Please provide some examples

Answer (score 0):

you can use lots of jquery plugin to achieve this ..like 
[http://jscroll.com/](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

and

http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/